# On Calculation of Weighted Percentage

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic

Today I am calculating a part of my final grade which is reflected by my assignment performance.

Each of them contributes 15% to my final grade. Here is the table, there are 5 of assignments in total, and the first row is the full mark of each assignment and the second row is the marks I got.

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
22 & 45 & 60 & 32 & 27 \\
20 & 31 & 43 & 27 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

Upon the first time I calculate the grades I had earned, this is what I did:

> Considering that I did not even do my last assignment, I will simply not calculate it; Meaning that, if imagine the marks I've gained as a 'pool', only assignments 1 - 4 will contribute to this 'pool', hence this pool is weighted in a total of $22+45+60+32 =159$, and the summed marks I have got is $20+31+45+27 = 121$, hence I 'filled' $\frac{121}{159}$ of this 60%-final-grade pool, hence so far I have got $\frac{121}{159} \times 60\% \simeq 45.7\%$

I calculted the second time, and this is what I did:

> If the 'pool-logic' is right, then the pool could also be contributed by all 5 assignments,  this time $22+45+60+32+27 = 186$, hence for this 75%-final-grade pool, I have got $\frac{121}{186} \times 75\% \simeq 48.8\%$

But how? I know that they're both wrong, as I should calculate my grade as the sum of each of them, as $\frac{20}{22} \times 15\% + \frac{31}{45} \times 15\% + ...$

How is this happening? Is this error caused by this 'pool' analogy? Where is the mistake of this analogy? Upon realizing this mistake, how can we correct this analogy if it can be corrected at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in failing to recognize that (for example) a single point in  the $[22]$ pool is **worth more** than a single point in the $[45]$ pool.

Your approach of adding the points together is **do-able**.  However this approach requires that you give each point it's proper weight.

Let $A$ denote the set $\{22,45,60,32,27\}$.

For $k \in A$:

- Let $~w_k$ denote the fraction $\dfrac{0.15}{k}.$
- Let $~s_k$ denote the score in the $[k]$ pool. 
  For example, $s_{22} = 20.$

So, the aggregate computation of your performance in the $5$ pools should be

$$\sum_{k \in A} s_k \times w_k. \tag1 $$

To explain the formula in (1) above, suppose (hypothetically) that you happened to score $27$ out of $27$ in the $[27]$ pool.

So, you are pretending that $s_{27} = 27$, rather than $s_{27} = 0.$

In that case, the amount earned from the $[27]$ pool would be

$$\left[27 \times \frac{0.15}{27}\right], ~~\text{rather than}~~ \left[0 \times \frac{0.15}{27}\right].$$